# Monitor tcp packet segmentation and packet retransmitting using wireshark in multiple IP Address

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark, ethernet

I having difficulty to monitor tcp packet segmentation and packet retransmitting using wireshark. We would like to monitor if there is any packet lost or retransmitting happened during the communication between server and client in our application.
We did tried to monitor single ip address for 1 day and the size of the file is very huge and it take very long time to open file to check every single packet. It is very time consuming and difficult to trace. Is there any method to save and monitor only if tcp packet segmentation/ retransmitting occur?

Answer (score 0):

You should limit your capture file to no more than ~100MB, you can do it by using stop conditions during capture setup. Check this link for more details:
"[The “Capture Options” dialog box](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureOptions.html)"

You can also use capture filters to save only desired traffic.